# how to import parquet files from s3 to postgresql rds

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, parquet, data-import

I'm trying to load a parquet file from s3 to AWS postgresql RDS. The data import using aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 is working fine for csv file but when I tried the similar way for parquet file, I get the below error:

> ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

In AWS docs, I see option for custom delimiter or zip file. Is it possible to import parquet data?

Comment: Did you find a way to solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Data import into an AWS PostgreSQL RDS supports what [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html) does. Although there is a PostgreSQL binary file format it doesn't support Parquet so in order to import the data you have to convert it to a text file or the PostgreSQL binary file format first.

Comment: I made a library to convert Parquet to Postgres’ binary format: https://github.com/adriangb/pgpq